# Chromium doesn't accept self-signed Root CA

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, certificate, chromium

I'm use Ubuntu 18.04 and Chromium browser 78.0.3904.70. I have an self-signed Root CA that I need import to Ubuntu. This certificate is need for launch localhost web app. I added certificate following this instructions.

```
sudo cp /path/to/selfsigned.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/ca-certificates/selfsigned.crt
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n selfsigned_ca -i /usr/share/ca-certificates/selfsigned.crt
```

And I still get NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in browser.

Any ideas what is wrong?

PS:

1. I also tried to use #allow-insecure-localhost Chrome flag.
2. I tried to copy .crt file in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates dir instead of /usr/share/ca-certificates.
3. I tried to export .crt file manually through the Chromium.

Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

For those using the snap version of Chromium, try to replace `$HOME` with `$HOME/snap/chromium/current/`.

```
certutil -d sql:$HOME/snap/chromium/current/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n selfsigned_ca -i /usr/share/ca-certificates/selfsigned.crt
```